# Getting a SQL View via Entity Framework returns incorrect result

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have a very simple View in SQL Server which looks something like this, Where the **Show** is a result of **LEFT JOIN** with **Character** table:

```
+---------+----------+----------------------+  
|  Name   | Surname  |         Show         |  
+---------+----------+----------------------+  
| Enoch   | Thompson | The Boardwalk Empire |  
| Anthony | Soprano  | The Sopranos         |  
| Walter  | White    | Breaking Bad         |  
+---------+----------+----------------------+
```

When I get this table via Entity Framework's `context.CharacterView.ToList()` in my application, the result looks like this:

```
+---------+----------+----------------------+  
|  Name   | Surname  |         Show         |  
+---------+----------+----------------------+  
| Enoch   | Thompson | The Boardwalk Empire |  
| Anthony | Soprano  | The Boardwalk Empire |  
| Walter  | White    | The Boardwalk Empire |  
+---------+----------+----------------------+
```

However, in DB the CharacterView is *as it should be.*

---

### Create view query

```sql
CREATE VIEW CharacterView AS
SELECT c.Name AS [Name], 
       c.Surname AS [Surname], 
       s.Name AS [Show]

FROM   [dbo].[Characters] AS c LEFT OUTER JOIN
       [dbo].[Shows] AS scen ON c.ShowId = s.Id
```

---

Comment: How do you know that the query is returning the results you mention?  Are you viewing it in the debugger?  Or are generating output?  If output, then lets see the code you're using to display it.

Comment: The results I mention as output are from the debugger. To clarify a bit - the problem is that the `context.CharacterView.ToList()` contains `Shows` that are not present in the `dbo.CharacterView` - that is EF does not reflect the DB correctly.

Comment: Thank you for the question and the answers below. The EF Designer gives you a "bad" hint:

warning 6002: The table/view 'yourView' does not have a primary key defined. The key has been inferred and the definition was created as a read-only table/view.

I added the message for people searching for this warning.

Answer (score 10):

Right on, D.Mac.  You solved a problem we have had for several weeks and we just got around to researching it.  We had a view where EF incorrectly "inferred" a primary key that wasn't unique and that caused data duplication just as you see above in Martin's SHOW column. Thanks.

SQL Server fix - to add the ROW_NUMBER to the view as a unique ID as D.Mac suggested:
SELECT ISNULL(CAST((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by T.PRODUCT_NAME)) as int), 0)  as ID, etc.

Now Entity Framework AUTOMATICALLY includes the ID column as an ENTITY KEY for the VIEW.  (Right-click on the view in the EDMX diagram and you should see the ID flagged as an ENTITY KEY)

Comment: Calling .AsNoTracking() also helps.

Comment: @balbelias: It indeed worked by adding .AsNoTracking(). But fail to understand how? If it's because of not having PK then how AsNoTracking helps? Any idea?

Comment: @milind-thakkar I assume EF uses key-valued storage for storing loaded entities in context and it obviously uses PK as key. Having not unique PK the loaded data became invalid after inserting in those storage (some rows are missed). Using .AsNoTracking() you make EF not to use those storage but just load and map data to POCO classes. Solution in answer above works because it adds unique PK (row number) and key-value storage starts  working properly.

Comment: Adding .AsNoTracking() as an answer. @balbelius, feel free to add the answer and I will delete mine

Answer (score 8):

Adding `.AsNoTracking()` as @balbelias said in comment fixed this for me.

Comment: Good article on how to use .AsNoTracking().  I had never heard of it.  https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/entity-framework-and-asnotracking/